# Codeigniter how to use jquery within controller

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, socket.io, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter along with nodejs for real time notifications. Now I simply want the users to notify about the recent changes happened in on of the page(controller).

Hence, I am using socketio along with nodejs to acheieve the notification system. The code goes like this:

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:5000' );

$( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
    var nameVal = $( "input[name=nameInput]" ).val();
    var msg = $( "input[name=messageInput]" ).val();
    socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } ); //LN1
    alert('posted'); //Sent from client side
    return false;
});

//Receive the notification as soon as posted(for now, will get the same values posted above)
    socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        alert('got response');
        var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
        var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' + data.message + '</li>';
        var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;
        $( "#messages" ).html( content );
    });
```

I also however wants to save the changes to the form, so I am posting the form values to a controller, which will save it to the database. After that I want this code to run.

So, I think if I can get it somehow like this, that would be better:

```
Class Myclass extends CI_Controller
{
 //....contructors etc.

public function save_form()
{
   $name = $this->input->post('nameInput');
   $msg = $this->input->post('messageInput');
   $this->load->model('my_model'); //For saving to database
   $saved = $this->my_model->save($name, $msg); //returns true is saved

   if($saved)
   {
      //Now notify user
      //Please now tell me how to call the socketio javascript from here
   }
   redirect('form_url'); //Redirect back to form, from where is was submitted
}

//....other functions
}
}
```

So can anybody tell me how to call the javascript from within the controller? Is that a good idea? Actually I could have used the way to call the controller from ajax and then using `$.ajax.done(function(){ socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } ); }` but its too late to make the ajax calls all the way threw.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create view file Socket.php

Class Myclass extends CI_Controller
{
        function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
    }

```
  public function save_form()
   {
     $name = $this->input->post('nameInput');
     $msg = $this->input->post('messageInput');
     $this->load->model('my_model'); //For saving to database
     $saved = $this->my_model->save($name, $msg); //returns true is saved

    if($saved)
    {
        $this->load->view('Socket.php');
    }
    redirect('form_url'); //Redirect back to form, from where is was submitted
   }
```

}